# Why not I return lbl_esdeger.text at if condition?

Tags: xcode, arrays, nsstring, uilabel

Why can not I lbl_esdeger.text string value? Thanks for help

selectedCountry = @"Kanıt";
    lblText.text = selectedCountry;

```
titlearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//KANAL D
[titlearray addObject:@"Annem Uyurken"];
[titlearray addObject:@"Arka Sokaklar"];
[titlearray addObject:@"Kanıt"];
[titlearray addObject:@"Kötü Yol"]; 


int i;
for (i=0; i<[titlearray count]; i++) 
{
    if ([titlearray objectAtIndex:i] == selectedCountry) 
    {
        lbl_esdeger.text = [titlearray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"--- %@ --- %@",[titlearray objectAtIndex:i],selectedCountry);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare strings using the method [`isEqualToString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) in the if condition:

```
if ([[titlearray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:selectedCountry])
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```